# .net MVC3 BeginTransaction() locks the table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, transactions

How can I read from the table when another transaction is processing?

Im using BeginTransaction(). So when another process try to read from that particular table I get a timeout because the previous transaction is holding the table.

How can I make the table to be readable when a transaction is ongoing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `isolationLevel` parameter, as shown in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx)

The isolation level you want depends on what you're trying to do, because the value you read will depend on whether the write has finished or not.

Comment: I am using using (var transaction = new TransactionScope()) for my Web Api application and when i am trying to request more then one time it giving the 403 response. What i came to know is because of the Transactions it is rejecting the Request so any optional method is available for the Transaction to work with multiple requests!!